# create.aar file without dependencies

Tags: android, build.gradle, aar

I am trying to create .aar file from Android Studio. The code I have written needs appcomapt v7 library. I don't want to add the dependency in the build.gradle file of my aar package but want it to take from the project it is added. Please suggest how to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it to your library module to use all the classes that Android needs, if your library doesn't use any of those classes, then you can make a jar library.

Now, when you compile your library in the app module, you can exclude the library dependency adding this to the compile line

```
compile('com.yourpage:yourlibrary:1.0.0'){
     exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution. I will try and let you know. Thanks for responding :)

Comment: @MobileAppDeveloper does this solution work?

Comment: @AmrAshraf this just ignore the package from the library when you compile the project, and use the dependency in your app module, if you have different versions, this should help you decide which version use, library one or project one.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to add the dependency in the build.gradle file of my aar package

You have to include it there, otherwise you can not compile your `aar`

> but want it to take from the project it is added

You can still do that:

If your library declares `appcompat-v7` version `23` and your app does not declare `appcompat-v7`, version `23` will be used in your app.

If your library declares `appcompat-v7` version `23` and your app declares `appcompat-v7` version `24`, version `24` will be used in your app.